# How to correctly upload file data using axios to rails 5 backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios, ruby-on-rails-5, multipartform-data

I want users to be able to upload a photo on my project and have it added to their profile. I think I might be doing the axios call wrong, because I've tried figuring out how to do this based on a mix of other stack overflow answers.

Here is the onSubmit handler for the small form:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const user = { user: avatarUser };
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('user[profpic]', file)
    formData.append('_method', 'PATCH')
    user.user.profpic = formData;
    addFileToProfile(user).then(closeModal());
  };
```

Here's the axios call:

```
export const addFileToProfile = (user) =>
  axios
    .post(`/api/users/${user.user.id}`, user, {
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    })
```

The controller is pretty standard, I'm using strong params so that's why I'm nesting the data under the key of `user`. I have been using routes for creating and patching users successfully, so I don't think the controller is the issue. I'll post the update action just in case, but it is working for things other than this:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update(user_params)
      render "api/users/show"
    else
      render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: 422
    end
  end
```

My server logs are pretty suspicious; it looks like for some reason what I sent using axios triggered a GET request:

```
Started POST "/api/users/5" for ::1 at 2021-11-27 22:24:06 -0500
Started GET "/[object%20FormData]" for ::1 at 2021-11-27 22:24:06 -0500
```

That's about it. I hope someone with more experience than me can interpret the logs there and figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue was mostly lying in too much nesting in the `handleSubmit` function. I would recommend making it simpler and passing along nothing but the ID and the  formData. I also added another header to the axios call. It's now working as expected!

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(`user[${photoType}]`, file)
  const user = { data: formData, id: avatarUser.id };
  upload(user).then(closeModal());
};
```

```
export const addFileToProfile = (user) => (
  axios
    .patch(`/api/users/${user.id}`, user.data, {
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data", processData: "false" },
    })
    .then((res) => res.data)
)
```